# Using html header/footers with html2pdfrocket

Tags: azure-web-app-service, wkhtmltopdf

Has anyone had success using html2pdfrocket with custom html header/footers?

I've got the following footer (not the dataUri has be shrunk for posting) that I'm trying to pass to the html2pdfrocket API but I just get a 500 error back.

```
var generatedFooter = "<div style=\"width:100%;text-align:right;margin-right:25px;padding-bottom:25px;\"><img src=\"data:image/png;base64,iVBOR....\" style=\"width:150px; margin-bottom:25px;\" /></div>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that html2pdfrocket doesn't support html strings for the header/footer.  Instead I created a webservice that returns a generated html page with the header information.

Just as a further FYI html2pdfrocket and wkhtmltopdf which it is based on require that the header html page has a  tag at the top otherwise the bottom of the page in a large view is shown instead.